# Merging pdf:s with pdfBox creates a unnecessary large file

Tags: java, pdf, merge, compression

Massive amount of hit on this topic but only crappy threads :(

I merge a bunch of pdf files with pdfBox. Easy with a class for the purpose.

But the reult is a very large file. I have no exact figure now but its easy twise the size compared to a merge done by a ordinary desctop app.

Not acceptable im afraid.

The problem seems to be similar to this (split in this case, same same but diffrent):
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-785

After some googling I think the problem is that the merge produces a barebones merged PDF file, and a large one at that, without compresson.

According this blog some java pdf libs can handle compression:
http://pdf-house.blogspot.com/

Itext handles this according with pdfstamper setFullCompression().
PDF/CompressPdfdocument.htm">http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0419_PDF/CompressPdfdocument.htm

But i also bumped in to the ghost script project.
https://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8229-putting-together-pdf-files

So, I need a second opinion. This ghost script seems cool, but itext does the trick according to google.

Am I on the right track? What to choose? One of the above or somthing intirely diffrent?

Tnx!

Comment: Are you using PDStream? There is a method addCompression() which might work out for you.

Comment: Yes, that could do the trick. Unfortinatily I have trouble finding any god exemples using the PDMemoryStream class. Can you assist?

Comment: I've had a poke about and it looks really hard to track this down. The documentation for pdfbox leaves a lot to be desired. All I can think of is writing out the large merged document and then reading it again whilst pushing it through a PDStream with compression. Or perhaps looking for some other library's compression.

Answer (score 2):

Try mixing PDFBox for merging with itext for compression.

See groovy example: http://pastebin.com/w8Rz8uha

I tested it with http://www.tobcon.ie/assets/files/test.pdf and uncompressed.pdf is 302kb and compressed.pdf is 58kb. (100 duplicated pages)